Why does PyGame Mixer play MP3s loaded with PyDub too fast on Windows, but correctly on Linux?
I have a situation where I need to load MP3 sounds into PyDub to edit them (specifically, trimming off 0.15 seconds of near-silence from their beginnings), then pass the trimmed result to PyGame to play them. I do not want to save the files in the edited state, mostly because this is a pre-existing OST. A tested "bench rig" of my method for doing this is:
s = pygame.mixer.Sound(pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(MP3_PATH)[0.15 * 1000 : ].get_array_of_samples())
s.play()

On Fedora 40 Linux, this works fine. But, on Windows 11, the audio plays at precisely four times its correct speed. It seems that this may be in PyDub's end, but is there a good programmatic workaround?
Notes:

The MP3 files are stereo.
I installed FFMpeg for PyDub MP3 support via Chocolatey on Windows.
This is an x64 system.

What I've tried to further diagnose the issue:

I tried loading through PyDub without the [0.15 * 1000 : ] trimming bit, the speed change was still there.
I tried just loading the MP3 files directly with PyGame, and it did not have the speed change. Only going through PyDub makes the change.
I tried different MP3 files. The results were the same for all of them.
I checked the sample rate of the MP3s, it is standard 44100 Hz.
I can't do this in production because the data is invalid after trimming, but I tried handing PyGame.Mixer.Sound the PyDub AudioSegment.raw_data() bytes. The speed change is still there.
I tried initializing PyGame Mixer with a quarter of the default 44100 sample rate. This countered the speed change, but I can tell it was sped up and then slowed down: The fidelity is terrible as there is no treble.
I don't think I can use PyDub's built-in playback system, as I also need to dynamically change the volume of the sounds as they are playing.

